# Approximate 2d surface using scipy.minimize L_BFGS_B

Tags: python, scipy

I need to reconstruct a heighfield `f(x,y) -> z` from a vector field `g(x,y) -> (a,b,c)`, according to a set of given equations, but I have an issue for computing the gradient (I am using L_BFGS_B because I think it's the only optimizer that will allow me to not explode memory).

I am having the following conflict:

- Images are 2d arrays, gradient is computed along each axis and needs two values per pixel
- Heightfield is only 1 variable per pixel (the height)

Therefore, after computing gradient, scipy complains that the function cannot return as gradient an array with (img_x * img_y, 2) shape. Only 1D shape with exact same count than heightfield array.

Am I missing something obvious here ?

## Detailed problem

I define three variables `nx`, `ny`, `nz`:

```
nx = g(x,y).x
ny = g(x,y).y
nz = g(x,y).z
```

Now, for each point (x,y) of the grid, I need to compute the height of the point (f(x,y)), according to the following equations:

```
nz * [f(x+1, y) - f(x,y)] == nx
nz * [f(x, y+1) - f(x,y)] == ny
```

I have tried expressing this in a loss function:

```
class Eval():
    def __init__(self, g):
        '''
        g: (x, y, 3)
        '''
        self.g = g

    def loss(self, x):
        depth = x.reshape(self.g.shape[:2])

        x_roll = np.roll(depth, -1, axis=0)
        y_roll = np.roll(depth, -1, axis=1)

        dx = depth - x_roll
        dy = depth - y_roll

        nx = self.g[:,:,0]
        ny = self.g[:,:,1]
        nz = self.g[:,:,2]

        loss_x = nz * dx - nx
        loss_y = nz * dy - ny

        self.error_loss = np.stack([loss_x, loss_y], axis=-1)

        total_loss = norm(self.error_loss, axis=-1)

        return np.sum(total_loss)

def grads(self, x):
    x_roll = np.roll(self.error_loss[:,:,0], -1, axis=0)
    y_roll = np.roll(self.error_loss[:,:,1], -1, axis=1)

    dx = self.error_loss[:,:,0] - x_roll
    dy = self.error_loss[:,:,1] - y_roll

    g_xy = np.stack([dx, dy], axis=-1)

    # g_xy has shape (x, y, 2)
    # BUT THIS MUST RETURN (x * y), not (x * y, 2) nor (x * y * 2)
    # WHAT SHOULD I RETURN HERE ? ||g_xy|| ?
```

And call it like this

```
vector_field = ... # shape: 1024, 1024, 3
x0 = np.random.uniform(size=vector_field.shape[:2])
ev = Eval(vector_field)
result = optim.fmin_l_bfgs_b(ev.loss, x0, fprime=ev.grads)
```

## Questions

- Is there a way to express those equations for resolving them in another way ? In theory, they are overconstrained linear system that could be resolved with least squares approach, but I cannot find how to reformulate the equations in the form of `Ax = b`
- Otherwise what should I return for my gradient ? or I am computing it properly ?

Comment: Just to make sure it works in general, did you try a derivative-free algorithm?

Comment: I have not achieved any result with derivative-free so far, due to memory error. But I can give it a try on a subset of the data. Which one would you recommend to try ?

Comment: I always start with `method='Nelder-Mead'`, of course :)

Comment: It's not converging, the loss remains stable after 250 iterations. Does that mean there is an error in the loss, like a sign error or something ?